# Kaggle Digit Recognizer Using SVM (e1071): Error in predict.svm(ret, xhold, decision.values = TRUE) : Model is empty

Tags: r, svm

I am trying to solve the digit Recognizer competition in Kaggle and I run in to this error.

I loaded the training data and adjusted the values of it by dividing it with the maximum pixel value which is 255. After that, I am trying to build my model.

Here Goes my code,

```
Given_Training_data <- get(load("Given_Training_data.RData"))
Given_Testing_data <- get(load("Given_Testing_data.RData"))

Maximum_Pixel_value = max(Given_Training_data)
Tot_Col_Train_data = ncol(Given_Training_data)
training_data_adjusted <- Given_Training_data[, 2:ncol(Given_Training_data)]/Maximum_Pixel_value
testing_data_adjusted <- Given_Testing_data[, 2:ncol(Given_Testing_data)]/Maximum_Pixel_value
label_training_data <- Given_Training_data$label
final_training_data <- cbind(label_training_data, training_data_adjusted)


smp_size <- floor(0.75 * nrow(final_training_data))
set.seed(100)
training_ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(final_training_data)), size = smp_size)
training_data1 <- final_training_data[training_ind, ]
train_no_label1 <- as.data.frame(training_data1[,-1])
train_label1 <-as.data.frame(training_data1[,1])
```

> ```
> svm_model1 <- svm(train_label1,train_no_label1) #This line is throwing an error
> ```

Error : Error in predict.svm(ret, xhold, decision.values = TRUE) :    Model is empty!

Please Kindly share your thoughts. I am not looking for an answer but rather some idea that guides me in the right direction as I am in a learning phase.

Thanks.

Update to the question :

```
trainlabel1 <- train_label1[sapply(train_label1, function(x) !is.factor(x) | length(unique(x))>1 )]
trainnolabel1 <- train_no_label1[sapply(train_no_label1, function(x) !is.factor(x) | length(unique(x))>1 )]
svm_model2 <- svm(trainlabel1,trainnolabel1,scale = F)
```

It didn't help either.

Comment: Most of the beginners are running into this problem. If someone can provide a clear answer, then it will be a lot beneficial in our learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the manual (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/e1071/e1071.pdf):

```
svm(x, y = NULL, scale = TRUE, type = NULL, ...)
...
Arguments:
...
x     a data matrix, a vector, or a sparse matrix (object of class 
Matrix provided by the Matrix package, or of class matrix.csr 
provided by the SparseM package,
or of class simple_triplet_matrix provided by the slam package).
y     a response vector with one label for each row/component of x. 
Can be either a factor (for classification tasks) or a numeric vector 
(for regression).
```

Therefore, the mains problems are that your call to `svm` is switching the data matrix and the response vector, and that you are passing the response vector as integer, resulting in a regression model. Furthermore, you are also passing the response vector as a single-column data-frame, which is not exactly how you are supposed to do it. Hence, if you change the call to:

```
svm_model1 <- svm(train_no_label1, as.factor(train_label1[, 1]))
```

it will work as expected. Note that training will take some minutes to run.

You may also want to remove features that are constant (where the values in the respective column of the training data matrix are all identical) in the training data, since these will not influence the classification.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I understand, if this has to work, I need to remove the constant features lets say column1 and column2 from the training data. and from the testing data point of view, I will be removing the columns column 1 and column2 as well. What if column3 in testing data is also constant? will I removing them from training and testing data as well ?

Comment: You _do not need_ to remove the constant features. It just improves the performance for training the model, since these features will not be used for evaluating the elements of the kernel gram matrix. Furthermore, the same features must be present in the training and testing data. Hence, if you remove features from the training data, remove also from the testing data; if a column is constant only in the testing data, do not remove it from either the training or testing data

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to scale it manually since svm itself will do it unlike most neural network package.

You can also use the formula version of svm instead of the matrix and vectors which is

```
svm(result~.,data = your_training_set)
```

in your case, I guess you want to make sure the result to be used as factor，because you want a label like 1,2,3 not 1.5467 which is a regression

I can debug it if you can share the data:Given_Training_data.RData

Comment: Its a kaggle dataset - Digit Recognizer Competition. I just took the train data from there and converted it into RData as I thought it would run the process faster. This is the link - https://www.kaggle.com/c/digit-recognizer/download/train.csv

Comment: Ok,right now I am busy working on my job, I will take a look at it after 10 hours working.